# Using List Table Filters for ALL Custom Post Types

Tags: wp-admin, wp-list-table

Is there a way to create sortable columns for admin tables across ALL post types?

I am working on a project with 7 Custom Post Types, and wondering if there is a better approach than using multiple *manage_edit-{Post-Type-Here}_sortable_columns* filters for each post type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to use the filters for each post type anyway. If you plan to leverage a bunch of dynamic filters that all call for all 7 post type slugs you could stick them in an array and loop through the filters with a foreach. Saves a little bit of code at least.

```php
$post_types = array(
    'ptype_one', 'ptype_two', 'ptype_three', 'ptype_four',
    'ptype_five', 'ptype_six', 'ptype_seven'
);

foreach ( $post_types as $type ) {
    add_filter( "manage_edit-{$type}_sortable_columns", "your_callback" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, this is exactly what I am looking at now.  
  
My curiosity was piqued after discovering a [Tuts+ article](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen--wp-24934) which describes in the "Other Usages" section that by using *manage_posts_columns* and *manage_posts_custom_column* hooks, the custom column will be shown in all manage posts screens (ie: across all custom post types).  

Apparently, for whatever reason, the same sort of thing does not hold true for the sortable column filters.

Comment: Yeah, good call on the double quotes. I just didn't think about it :)